# Iterate over text file and replace in a loop python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to Python and need help with a simple issue.

I have a text file "alias.txt" and need to iterate over the aliases in the file and create a new file (or stdout) where the text looks like this;

```
#!/bin/python3
import alias.txt

alias_str = "ma <alias>\nmda -a <alias> mail-relay <alias>@ant.domain.com\n"
print (alias_str.replace("<alias>", "<aliases from alias.txt>"))
```

So the output should be something like;

```
ma alias1
mda -a alias1 mail-relay alias1@ant.domain.com

ma alias2
mda -a alias2 mail-relay alias2@ant.domain.com

etc...
```

Where the alias file looks like;

```
alias1
alias2
alias3
etc...
```

Comment: What does your alias.txt look like? Can you really `import` it, i.e. does it contain python source code?

Comment: added to question above

Comment: @AbdulrahmanBres please make sure to read the question and linked duplicate carefully. your linked duplicate does not apply here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to open and read the file, as opposed to importing it:

```
with open('alias.txt') as f:
    for alias in f:
        alias_str = "ma <alias>\nmda -a <alias> mail-relay <alias>@ant.domain.com\n"
        print (alias_str.replace("<alias>", alias.strip()))
```

and if you want to create a new file, instead of just printing the lines:

```
with open('alias.txt') as f:
    with open('alias2.txt', 'w') as f2:
        for alias in f:
            alias_str = "ma <alias>\nmda -a <alias> mail-relay <alias>@ant.domain.com\n"
            f2.write(alias_str.replace("<alias>", alias.strip()))
```

Comment: Probably good to use `alias.strip()` to get rid of any trailing whitespaces

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! @Nordle In the interest of understanding may I ask for an explanation too?

Comment: Of course! We use a context manager (the `with`) to open the files, so that they automatically close when we finish up, and we specify `'w'` for the second file to state we want to write to it, instead of the default which is read.

Then we simply make a loop over each "line" in the file, use that line to replace the instances as in your example, then write that amended line to the new file. After that, we repeat the loop until we use every line available in the file.